# Connect another LAN to WAN port of Zywall 10w

Tags: firewall, dhcp

Preamble: In my company we add a new Vodafone's router that's already compromised my working DHCP server. 
That's because Vodafone refuse to disable the DHCP server of their router. 
So I figure out to split the lan in 2 subnets and put a firewall in the middle to block the DHCP server.

The firewall I'm using is an old Zyxel Zywall 10w but I think it's ok for the purpose. 
It has 2 ports (1 LAN and 1 WAN). I configured all the firewall rules but there is a problem. The WAN led isn't blinking so it doesn't work.

I think it's because it want a WAN attached to the WAN port, I'm connecting another LAN. Is it the problem? There is an option to set this? (maybe encapsulation, rip, etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually doing anything *that* wrong.

From a router's point of view, there's nothing really that different between a WAN and a LAN, it's just a different block of addresses, but it's all Ethernet (or TCP/IP, depending where you're looking from) really.

Things I'd check.

- Is the cable between the Voda router and your Zyxel working?
- Have you configured the WAN port to expect DHCP?
- Are you sure that the Zyxel actually works?

Comment: Yes the cable is working, not sure if the zyxell works cause it's old. Yes I forward all the the traffic that don't match the rules of blocking port 67and68 that are the dhcp ports.
I have to use cross or it's the same?

Comment: Shouldn't need a cross-over cable on any consumer/SoHo level equipment.

Comment: Or generally, anything made in the last 10 years.  Even most pro stuff seems to support MDI-X